# В конце не ставить запятую

Tags: javascript

Формирую строку

```
    for (var i = 0; i < json_length; i++) {

  tmppie_traffic_source+='{"title" : '+'"'+json.data[i].name+ '","litres" : '+json.data[i].visits+'},';

                        }
```

Как сделать так,что в последней итерации цикла к конце не ставилась запятая?

```
json.data[i].visits+'},';
```

Сейчас решаю проблему через `replace`, но думаю можно как то иначе

Answer (score 3):

Используйте для конструирования строки в формате JSON функцию [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

К сожалению, пример кода привести не могу, потому что не видно контекста в вашем коде. К тому же, вероятно, вы пытаететсь решать [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/183314).

Comment: Вам плюс, но, исходя из задачи, визиты нужно превратить в литры, так что простым `JSON.stringify` тут не обойтись :) Возможно, в свойства элементов нового массива должны попасть не все свойства элементов исходного его.

Comment: @br3t, в таком случае, мне кажется, лучше сконструировать новый массив средствами языка, а затем его серилиазовать. То есть всеми способами стараться использовать библиотечную реализацию этого. Тут даже не понятно, насколько ТС устраивает наличие кавычек в входных данных

Comment: @br3t, у [`JSON#stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) есть аргумент, который позволяет фильтровать что попадёт в результат.

Comment: @Other но для переименования свойств в объектах в массиве не получится простой функции. А за ссылку спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = { data: [
             {name: "John", visits: 23},
             {name: "Mary", visits: 45}
           ]};
var json_length = json.data.length;

var items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json_length; i++) {
  items.push('{"title" : "'+json.data[i].name+'","litres" : '+json.data[i].visits+'}');
}  
tmppie_traffic_source = items.join(",");

console.log(tmppie_traffic_source );
```

Answer (score 1):

Делайте проще:

```js
let data = ['A', 42, true];

let json = `{${data.map(e => `["type": "${typeof e}", "name": "${e}"]`).join(',')}`;
console.info(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_length; i++) {
  tmppie_traffic_source+='{"title" : '+'"'+json.data[i].name+ '","litres" : '+json.data[i].visits+'}'+((i+1)==json_length)?'':',';
}
```

Comment: Для проверки последнего элемента наверное лучше `i===(json_length-1)`

Comment: да i===(json_length-1) или (i+1)===json_length

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = {};
json.data = [{name:'a', visits: 1, smth: 'z'}, {name:'b', visits: 2, smth: 'y'}];
var json_length = json.data.length;
var tmppie_traffic_source = [];

for (var i = 0; i < json_length; i++) {
  tmppie_traffic_source.push({
    title: json.data[i].name,
    litres: json.data[i].visits
  });
}
tmppie_traffic_source = JSON.stringify(tmppie_traffic_source);
console.log(tmppie_traffic_source.replace(/[\[\]]/g, ''));
```